# Using sed script to replace specific parts of filtered lines

Tags: sed

Given an xml file consisting of lines like below:

```
<dependency field="no_change" name="test" conf="blahblah"/>
<dependency field="to_be_picked_up" name="test" conf="blahREPLACE_ME"/>
```

I would like to be able to identify lines where the value of field is equal to the **to_be_picked_up** (which can be anything apart from a specific string e.g. **no_change**) and replace the string **REPLACE_ME** with a specific string.

I have used the following command to do some line-level changes but I am not sure how I can script the logic for replacing **REPLACE_ME** only in lines where the value of the field can be anything apart from the to_be_picked_up and locate the change within the conf="".

```
sed -e 's/<dependency \(.*\)\(\.*\)>/\<dependency \1\/\>/'
```

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools to process XML. Use something like `xmlstarlet` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sed to edit XML. Use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a tool based on libxml I happen to maintain, you can write

```
open file.xml ;
for //dependency[@field="to_be_picked_up"]/@conf
    set . xsh:subst(., 'REPLACE_ME', 'RESULT') ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/field="no_change"/!s/REPLACE_ME/whatever/'
```

Using `xmlstarlet`, it would be:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//dependency[@field!="no_change"]/@conf' -x 'concat(substring-before(.,"REPLACE_ME"), "whatever", substring-after(., "REPLACE_ME"))'
```